# Build a house or building a house

Tags: grammar

1. The first test I want to do is build a house.
2. The first test I want to do is building a house.

Are both correct? If so, what are the differences?

Answer (score 1):

I think what is happening here:

> ... to do is build a house

is an example where if two close constituents share the same "head", the second "head" can be omitted.  Similar to "Take the red cup and plate = take the red cup and the (red plate."  So this is an abbreviated version of "to do is to build a house."

Meaning *to build* is an infinitive.  So you are asking if it's better to use the infinitive verbal or gerund verbal.

From [this](http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/nouns/gerunds-infinitives/), here's a good heuristic to use in this situation.  The right one depends on the context and exactly what you are trying to say:

> Gerunds
>
> Gerunds are best for use in sentences about actions that are real or
>   complete, or that have been completed.
>
> • I stopped worrying about the future.
>
> In this example, the worrying was real and it happened until I
>   stopped.
>
> • We really enjoy climbing mountains.
>
> In this example, the climbing is real and it’s something we like to
>   do.
>
> Infinitives
>
> Infinitives are best for use in sentences about actions that are
>   unreal or abstract, or that will occur in the future.
>
> • I’d like you to think about something.
>
> In this example, I’m asking you to think about something, but the
>   thinking hasn’t happened yet.
>
> • Can we take a walk without you stopping to smoke?
>
> In this example, we’re talking about taking a walk and the smoking
>   hasn’t happened yet.

Since the house hasn't been built yet, you probably want to use the first example you provided.  But, if this is something like a video game, and the house has been built before, then "building" may be more appropriate.

Comment: Building a   house is the first thing I want to do. :) Gerunds as nouns are also feasible.